# Silent failure during account suspension

Tags: bug, status-declined, moderator-abilities, account-suspension

I tried to suspend a user for 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999 days, and the form clicked through as if it succeeded, but the suspension did not apply.

If the maximum is 365 days, then either the form should prevent me from putting in a higher number or it should fail with an explicit notice.

Comment: It's gotta be longer than 365 days... There are users suspended 'til 2038 around.

Comment: @Shog9 In that case, I'll put the actual number I tried in.

Comment: Maybe I just over-ran whatever data type is taking that input.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather it just go 365 silent into the night and let you go on your merry boxing day?

Comment: @random Yes, that'd be fine, too.

Comment: Or even just provide a radio button for "max suspension."

Comment: What did that user do to be suspended for that time?

Comment: @Gamecat New unregistered user with no prior history posted abusive spam. Suspending forever beats deletion because the IP address is then unusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly recommend against this course of action.

Lots of pointless suspensions is bad news for a site, and it clutters the *valid* timed suspensions.

I cannot provide specific details because it would be a recipe for avoiding certain filters that we have.

The only reason I can think of to not delete a spam account is if you think they're not smart enough to clear cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Apparently, some sites maintain an indefinitely-suspended "spam account" and merge new spammers in with it. Deletion's certainly easier, so if this suspension trick is considered harmful, we can certainly stick to that. Why anyone would want to suspend for a long time aside, isn't the silent failure I encountered still a usability bug?

Comment: @isaac on SU they merge all the bad accounts into one katamari ball of giant badness, but it's more a hobby than an actually *useful* thing to do, IMO. Deletion is best. Remember that very little is hard-deleted in our system anyway...

Comment: Hint taken. We'll trust in the subterranean magic.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use Destroy for this purpose?

Comment: @isaac destroy simply ensures all their posts are deleted as well. Best for spam users, yes.