# Suspending user for more than 999 days fails silently, still sends message

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, account-suspension

waiwai933 ran into this on English.SE, and I've confirmed - attempting to suspend a user for longer than 999 days results in a message being sent, but the user left unsuspended.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Select "contact user privately (includes suspension)" from a user's mod menu
2. Select a template
3. Check the "also suspend this user" checkbox
4. Enter 2555 in the "for ____ days" entryfield
5. Press the "Notify and Suspend" button.
6. Observe that a message has been sent and the user's account annotated, but not suspended.

#### Expected behavior

The obvious behavior would be to suspend the user for the specified number of days. However, if there is a limitation on suspension length, this should be noted in the UI and enforced in a less confusing manner: display an error, or at very least, prevent the form from being submitted until a valid number is entered.

#### Ranting

Tim Stone notes in comments that [this bug has been posted before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95848/silent-failure-during-account-suspension), and sure enough, this does appear to be describing the same behavior. However, I would like to emphasize the confusing, potentially-harmful nature of *sending a message to the user being suspended* **while failing to actually suspend them:** if unnoticed, this could be rather counter-productive.

If deletion is the desired action for users who are violating the ToS and have no expectation of being allowed back on the site in any reasonable amount of time, then **this should also be noted in the UI**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silent failure during account suspension](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95848/silent-failure-during-account-suspension)

Comment: @Tim True, although that one ignored the error case and got status-declined for other reasons

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yeah, I don't really understand why the actual issue was overlooked just because of the action being taken.

Comment: Can't duplicate.  Please add a diamond after my user name so I can verify bug.

Comment: Someone needed to be suspended for ***three years***!?!

Comment: @dmckee: 7 years. To hit that magical non-ToS-violating age, y'know?

Comment: Ah. That's clever.

Comment: @Adam: I'll duplicate for you, and you can still be a part of the testing.  ;)

Comment: @Bill Sounds good!  I'll await my ban email for 3,000 days.  Just make sure to test before Marc fixes it...

Comment: @Shog - you should do 2556 days - there's a leap year in there.

Comment: @JNK: Actually, there are 2 leap years in the next 7 years. So it would be 2557 days.

Comment: @siva - SQL Server 2008 r2 disagrees: `SELECT DATEADD(day, 2556, GETDATE())`

Comment: Regardless of 2556, you now have 5000 days available to you - so if a foetus starts using the site, you can ban them until they can do so without violate the terms. But hey... kudos to that foetus.

Comment: @Shog9 you found a six year old? Somehow I doubt that... did Jeff [leave his computer unlocked](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/11/dont-forget-to-lock-your-computer.html) near his kid or something?

Comment: @nhinkle: it's either a precocious youngster, or a troll - and lord knows I would *never* accuse anyone of trolling.

Comment: @Shog9 it wouldn't amaze me to find out Jon's lad has been trying to help fix the internet

Comment: @Shog9: Found a new 3 year suspension on Eng.SE - Thought the system did not have such upper limits and that led me to your question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's no longer relevant as moderators are now intentionally restricted from suspending users from longer than 365 days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I will fix this later today. Thanks.

Comment: Verified - 5000 day suspension works, 5001 days produces a descriptive error and does not send a message. Much better - Thanks!